# Failed to allocate bytes in large images OpenCV

Tags: .net, opencv, out-of-memory

I am processing very large images but I get an exception that informs me "Failed to allocate 991623040 bytes"

I have 64bit Win7 and 8GB ram. Isn't it ridiculus that failing when smaller than 1GB?

How can I solve this problem?

```
public bresenhamCircle()
    {
        if (path != null) //path is a string represents the file path
        {
            using (IplImage orgImg = new IplImage(rc.imgeYolu, LoadMode.GrayScale))
            {
                if (rc.sekizBit)
                {
                    orgImg.ToBitmap();
                }
                else
                {
                    //binary image
                }

                using (IplImage imgLabel = new IplImage(orgImg.Size, BitDepth.F32, 1))
                {
                    using (CvBlobs blobs = new CvBlobs())
                    {


                        uint result = blobs.Label(orgImg, imgLabel);
                        blobs.FilterByArea(10, 130);
                    }
                }


            }
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("smtg..");
        }

    }
```

I am getting the error message at this line :
using (IplImage imgLabel = new IplImage(orgImg.Size, BitDepth.F32, 1))

Comment: Lets see your code that generated this error. Also note what version of opencv you are using.

Comment: using (IplImage imgLabel = new IplImage(orgImg.Size, BitDepth.F32, 1)) this line generates the error. orgImage size is 18000x13000 and it is defined from a file by using the code:IplImage orgImg = new IplImage(path, LoadMode.GrayScale) OpenCV version is 2.2

Comment: edit your original post and put the code inside a code block.

Answer (score 1):

It could be several reasons; most likely because you have memory leaks. We would need to see your code, the code above looks like you are not declaring the images at pointers using the "*" operator, but that is probably a typo. Also just because you have 64 bit windows and 8 GB of RAM, if you are using a 32 bit build of opencv, you only have access to 2 GB of RAM. I would recommend downloading the latest SVN version of opencv and building in 64 bit mode and enabling tbb.

Comment: Please note that opencv 2.2 has been plagued with lots of problems, you might be better off going with opencv 2.1. With that being said, the latest svn should have most of those problems in 2.2 fixed.

Answer (score 1):

If you not running your application in 64 bit mode then you are not using 8 GB of RAM. Also out of memory is caused by insufficient contiguous virutal address spaces not physical address spaces refer article http://vpnchoudhary.blogspot.com/2011/03/out-of-memory-exception-simple.html for details on how memory mgmt of 32 bit application.

First verify if your appication is running in 64 or not. Open task mgr and see if your appication is appended by *32 at the end. if yes then your application is running in 32 bit mode. Compile your application for 64 bit. it should resolve your issue.
If your application is already running in 64 bit then your appliation is leaking memory, but i highly doubt it as you are using "using" which should take care of disposing object.
Also with 64 bit application you got huge virtual address spaces which is hard of exhaust, you application will start thrashing (very slow) but will rarely go out of memory.